# Call a function for a filtered dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having data such as ,

data

```
ID          filter
1             A
2             A
3             A
4             A
5             B
6             B
7             B
8             B
```

I want to apply a function for the dataframe,

```
def add(x):
    y = x+1
    return(y)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *                 
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

ol_val = udf(add, StringType())

data = data.withColumn("sum",ol_val(data.ID))
```

this gives an output,

data

```
ID          filter        sum
1             A            2
2             A            3
3             A            4
4             A            5
5             B            6
6             B            7
7             B            8
8             B            9
```

**I want to apply this function only when filter = A** and **for the remaining part I want it be NULL**. The output I want here is,

data

```
ID          filter        sum
1             A            2
2             A            3
3             A            4
4             A            5
5             B            NULL
6             B            NULL
7             B            NULL
8             B            NULL
```

Here the value is NULL because it didnt satisfy the condition filter= A. I want the function to be applied only when filter = A.

Can anybody help me in changing the code inorder to get this output in pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to use [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=functions#pyspark.sql.functions.when) and [otherwise](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=functions#pyspark.sql.Column.otherwise). By the way you don't have to create that `UDF`.

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, "a"),
    (1, "b"),
    (3, "c")
  ]).toDF(["id", "filter"])

df.select("*", when(col("filter") == lit("a"), col("id") + 1).otherwise(None).alias("result")).show()
```

If you really need to call that function, you can simply replace `col("id") + 1` by     `yourUDF(col("id"))`

Comment: Instead of adding one, can you help me in modifying the code to call the function add with col('id') when filter = a? I tried changing this code. But facing some errors. It would be helpful if you can modify this code to call the function